# Programmatically open System Information

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to programmatically open Window's "System Information" across different Window's version. At the moment it involves opening a `cmd.exe` window which then finds "System Information".

The problem is that I have an extraneous black command-line window while the "System Information" is open. Is there a way of doing without this extra window?

Comment: Could you show us some code so that we don't have to guess what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known app, like Wordpad, the reason that cmd.exe can find it.  Just use ShellExecute to open msinfo32.exe.  For example:

```
#include <shellapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")
...
// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_INFO) {
            ShellExecute(hDlg, L"open", L"msinfo32.exe", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            break;
        }
    // etc..
}
```

Which assumes you added a button to the About dialog with identifier IDC_INFO.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to start the Microsoft System Information dialog](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/sysinfodlg.aspx) on codeproject.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing MSInfo32 programmatically is explained in [How to start the Microsoft System Information dialog](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/sysinfodlg.aspx)